# Why has this transaction failed?

Tags: transactions, tokens, rinkeby

Getting familiar with the geth client and within some code followed a tutorial ([HERE](https://goethereumbook.org/transfer-tokens/)) to transfer tokens from an address. When I check the transaction on EtherScan, it has failed:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xf53488d996a532ae78080a23c54384c8f58438db02130f039b0e08dacf760f86

Not quite sure how to debug this and would appreciate any pointers on this.

Here is copy of my code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    ethereum "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/sha3"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {

    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("49be7f9b459942977f07f99653b5b042144baefa092c5ac833d6ec9893a5b8dd")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)

    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    value := big.NewInt(0) // Transfering Tokens doesnt need ETH values

    //gasLimit := uint64(21000)

    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x4592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d")

    tokenAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x28b149020d2152179873ec60bed6bf7cd705775d")

    transferFnSignature := []byte("transfer(address,uint256")

    hash := sha3.NewKeccak256()

    hash.Write(transferFnSignature)

    methodID := hash.Sum(nil)[:4] // read up go lang slices

    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(methodID))

    paddedAddress := common.LeftPadBytes(toAddress.Bytes(), 32)
    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(paddedAddress))

    amount := new(big.Int)
    amount.SetString("1000000000000000000000", 10)

    paddedAmount := common.LeftPadBytes(amount.Bytes(), 32)

    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(paddedAmount))

    var data []byte

    data = append(data, methodID...)
    data = append(data, paddedAddress...)
    data = append(data, paddedAmount...)

    gasLimit, err := client.EstimateGas(context.Background(), ethereum.CallMsg{
        To:   &toAddress,
        Data: data,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(gasLimit)

    /*
        Generate Transation Type
    */

    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, tokenAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)

    /*
        Signing Tx with Sender's Private Key
    */

    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.HomesteadSigner{}, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    /*
        Broadcasting Transaction to Network
    */

    err = client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf(" tx sent: %s\n", signedTx.Hash().Hex())

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could share your code. The transaction data doesn't start with the expected function selector. From the tutorial, the function signature is `transfer(address,uint256)`, which is then hashed with keccak256 to get the 4-byte prefix `0xa9059cbb`, but your transaction starts with `0x30c48a31`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function signature is wrong. It's missing a right parenthesis. This line:

```
transferFnSignature := []byte("transfer(address,uint256")
```

should be this instead:

```
transferFnSignature := []byte("transfer(address,uint256)")
```

Comment: hey..its still failing...`unable to locate transfer log` https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0cc47e36bf89eda8bd51f8a24a90f0d4bf77f8541d423101461c384a8f7c75ff

Comment: As far as I can tell from https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x28b149020d2152179873ec60bed6bf7cd705775d#balances, the sending account doesn't own any tokens, so of course it can't transfer any.